# How to style the total field in gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravityforms

I'm trying to style the total pricing field in gravity forms but unable to find the accurate class that would reflect the changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

.gfield_total (entire field)
.ginput_container (container for input)
.ginput_total (the input itself)

To target the total in one specific form, you can use '.gfield_total_141_' or '.ginput_total_141' but replace 141 with your form id.